# How do I get all the days of a specific month in Windows API?

Tags: winapi

How do I get all the days of a specific month in Windows API ?

My request is not the current day, but the days of the month as a whole.

Comment: You don't really need an API for that. You can easily write your own function for it. The days of the months are all fixed except for February, for which you have to take leap years into considerations.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to know how many days has a given month in a given year.
I'm not aware of an API for this Win32.

Actually the implementation of this is pretty trivial, january has 31 days march has 31 days, april has 30 days etc. February can have 28 or 29 days depending if we are in a leap year or not.

You can determine if y is a leap year with following formula where y is the year :

(y % 4 == 0) ? ( (y % 100 == 0) ? ( (y % 400 == 0)? 1 : 0) : 1) : 0;

This should be enough information to enable you to write a function that returns the number of days of a given month in a given year.

Have also a look the the [Win32 time functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I really want to know how many days in a given month in a given year .

But months we have in Saudi Arabia is not fixed.

The same month, sometimes 30 days and sometimes 29.

Comment: Rules for the number of days in a month for the gregorian calender can be found here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month#Julian_and_Gregorian_calendars . If you are referring to the islamic calendar it's another story, maybe you can find some information here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar

Comment: @SecurityMatt: what's the problem with the formula ? This formula doesn't give the number of days in a month but it only determines if a given year (here y) is a leap year or not.